# Forward bias or reverse bias

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, current, diodes, biasing

What do we take, the flow direction of electronic current or conventional current through a diode if forward biased?

Comment: Conventional current follows the arrow.

Comment: The only time we actually might think about 'electron flow' is ... Oh... NEVER.    Every schematic you ever see will be written with 'conventional current' (+ to -) as the 'current flow'.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but I'll try to answer.

Electron current is always in the opposite direction to conventional current and this has nothing to do with diodes. Electrons have negative charge so they go from the negative pole to the positive pole of a battery but the current (conventional current) goes from positive to negative.

Conventional current is much more practical to use in electronics and it doesn't matter if it is positive charges going in one direction or negative charges going in the opposite direction.  Thinking about the flow of actual electrons is almost never useful, always use conventional current.

When a diode is forward biased (anode has a more positive voltage than cathode) it will conduct electricity from anode to cathode (conventional current flow). And when a diode is reverse biased it will not conduct at all.

Comment: Exactly!  The conventional current direction is more intuitive because it matches our notion that "something" flows from where there is more of it to where there is less of it.